# OP edited an answer to ask for clarification instead of editing his question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I came across this question the other day: [How to call a C# static method from Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555102/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-static-method-from-jquery/46820027)

The OP asked a question and got a number of answers, but they didn't seem to solve his problem. Instead of editing his question to further clarify his question, or posting a comment on an existing answer to get a better understanding of the answer, he instead directly edited someone's answer to ask for further clarification.

The edit was approved here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17521458

However, if you take a look at the screenshots he posted instead of blindly accepting any edit which increases a post's length, you'd see he edited the answer to basically say "this answer isn't working for me, and I don't know why."

So I saw this, and figured the best thing to do was to suggest an edit, with a clear explanation in the comment section for the Reviewers to see. You can see this suggested edit (by more robo-reviewers) was rejected here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17675069

Is there any other actions I should have done to remedy this post (e.g. comment at the original author of the answer)? Should I simply wait until I have 2k rep so that the buck isn't passed to robo-reviewers who don't read the question?

Comment: This is a *very* difficult problem to solve with suggested edits, as you have seen.  You'd be better off just flagging the post for moderator involvement and letting them handle the situation; make sure you explain specifically what all of the problems are (there are several in this case) and what all they'd need to do.  Even if you could edit the post to fix it, you'd still want to flag to have those reviewers dealt with.

Comment: @Servy Thank you Servy, I will flag the answer for moderator attention. That didn't occur to me as an action I should take, so I will keep this in mind going forward.

Comment: When you have sufficient reputation, the correct course of action would be to rollback the inappropriate edit.  You should probably still flag it for moderator attention, pointing out that the change was reviewed and approved and should not have been — the reviewers should be chastised, but that's a moderator task, not one for ordinary mortals like us.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no, don't do that! The moderator can override the review, same as with the author. This is what that feature was meant for, otherwise editor would never know.