# What to do with faulty edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

What is the appropriate behavior when you see a post which was [faulty edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/8097737) by another user (not the post owner) and was approved in the review Suggested Edits. For example an edit that fixes wrong code in other people's question.

- Just edit the post
- Rollback the edit, or ask for a rollback
- Ask a question on meta about the faulty edit
- flag for in need of moderator intervention
- Additional leave an comment for the users who edited and reviewed the edit.

I would like to have a little guide which could also be used as an FAQ, since I couldn't find a guide on how to deal with this.

---

Related Question:

- [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/8097737)
- [Are we supposed to flag bad reviews?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280649/8097737)
- [Guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/155539#155539)
- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251)
- [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390)

Comment: I think there are multiple situations that each require a different approach: 1. A singly bad edit; 2. A user constantly making bad edits; 3. A user constantly approving bad edits

Comment: " _an edit that fixes wrong code in other people's question_ " That this gets approved shows that there are people behaving like "review robots". Like usual. I had to rollback an approved edit this morning.

Comment: @KarelG fixing code is fine as long as it isn't the thing it is being asked about.

Comment: @Braiam be careful there. There has been questions where the OP is facing an issue where the problem can be solved by fixing a typo or using appropriate function names. Editing that question would cause confusion. A detailed comment and a close vote is sufficient there. Or an answer if you want.

Comment: @Braiam: That's incorrect.  The only edit that should be made to code in a question is to fix formatting, and that's only if correcting formatting will not fix the problem issue (for instance, Python code where the indentation is the problem).

Comment: @KenWhite "Editing Code in Questions; Do: Fix Syntax (non-closed brackets, missing semi-colons, etc.), unless they are relevant to the question
Fix typos (misspelled function calls, variable names, etc.), unless they are relevant to the question" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/792066

Comment: @Braiam: Yep. That's a small quote from a much larger post. The most relevant portion is the opening paragraph, which you neglected to include: *Code in questions should only be edited for formatting and readability.*, which is exactly what I said in my previous comment. And the absolutely most important part of the linked post is omitted entirely: *When in doubt, click 'Skip'. "Learn to love that Skip button."*

Comment: @KenWhite well, how about Shog's, then? ["The correct response is to edit the question such that it doesn't suck"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278014/792066) If the question sucks, and we have the ability to make it so that it doesn't sucks anymore, why shouldn't we? Not removing irrelevant parts of the question (ie. copy-n-pasting error) when the rest of the question makes sense, is a disservice. BTW, Shog advice is in direct contradiction with that part of the FAQ. That's why I prefer the help center and his posts.

Comment: @Braiam: With all props to Shog, there's a difference between telling someone *See the FAQ*, which is an official portion of the site, and *Well, let's go ask Shog.* If it's in the FAQ, there's a reason. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite the thing with the "FAQ" is that anyone can edit it. I hate that FAQ, with all my heart, I prefer the help center and failing that SE employees. I just linked the FAQ because it's has that as explicit, otherwise I would haven't used it at all.

Comment: @Braiam: And anyone can roll back invalid or incorrect edits. :-) The FAQ is a good, consistent location that can be easily located and linked to help new users or answer... well, FAQs. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite To roll back an invalid edit you need at least 2k reputation else you can only suggest an edit. The FAQ is indeed good but not easily to find especially for new users. Since the is not direct link to the FAQ from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), it is also split between [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) and [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: @devpuh: And? You also need at least 2k to edit the post in the first place. *Anyone* in both Braiam and my comments were not to be taken *literally*, as in *anyone who might stumble across the FAQ*. And the two FAQ pages are separate because they should be - the list on SO is FAQs that are typically only relevant at SO and SO Meta, while the list on MetaSE is for site-wide (applies to most or all of the SE sites) FAQs. I don't have a problem bookmarking both pages; Chrome supports more than one bookmark. :-)

Comment: Fix the faulty edit and move on. Things tend to get debated endlessly on Stack Overflow. Don't get drawn in. Fix it and move on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you see this happening, there are a few things to do.

- If you have full edit privileges (2000 points or more), you can just roll back.
- If you do not have full edit privileges, you can't roll back. You can make  a a new edit that restores the post to its original state. If you do so, you should say so in the Edit Summary - otherwise reviewers will think *you* are the one making a weird edit!
- If the approval (or rejection) is on one of your own posts, you can simply overrule the reviewer's decision.
- If you see users consistently making bad edits, you can post a comment on one of their posts that have an approved edit. They'll get a notification about your comment.
  Or, you can warn a mod right away, and they can look into it. To do this, you use a custom mod flag on one of their posts.
- Similarly, if you see someone consistently Approving bad edits (or Rejecting good ones!) you can flag one of their posts for moderator attention.

When bringing cases of bad editing / bad reviewing to the attention of the moderators, provide enough evidence for the moderators. As a rule of thumb, find 3 cases of bad edits / bad reviews in the last 2 days. That will give the moderators enough material to work with.
The moderator can then give the editor or reviewer a temporary suspension; this is meant to protect the site from the bad edits and bad reviews, but mostly to instruct the editor / reviewer. To give them some time to realize that they were doing things wrong. Many of these editors and reviewers mean well, and just need a little instruction.

Comment: Note that if you don't have full edit privileges, this is a difficult problem to fix with Suggested Edits, [as I discovered.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358162/op-edited-an-answer-to-ask-for-clarification-instead-of-editing-his-question) The same type of robo-reviewers who approved a dumb edit will likely reject your edit attempting to correct it. I was advised to raise a flag for moderator attention in the case when I didn't have sufficient permission to edit.

Comment: @C.Helling True - all you can do is make a good edit summary. Even then you can only hope that the reviewers will pay attention, as you discovered the hard way :-(

Comment: I wouldn't advise "back-editing" a bad edit. If you don't have the rollback privilege it's usually better to leave a comment pointing out what was wrong with the edit. Some people do bad edits in good faith (been there myself). Use moderator flags only in case of serious problems (like repeat offenders).

Answer (score 3):

Your description is a little bit vague, and can't be answered as it's very general.

Your action should depend on several things:

- Did this happen only once?
- Is the user making many bad edits recently?
- Is the rollback enough, or you can improve the post further?

If it's the first case, then rollback (or edit) and move on. However, if you notice that the same user is constantly  approving (or making) bad edits, you might need to flag the post and write down what you think.

Comment: Is there a difference between edit or rollback? According to [What is a 'rollback'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) the rollback also clears any spam and "rude or abusive" flag. Does the user who made the edit still get the reputation? And what about the (robo) reviews?

Comment: @devpuh If you want to fix and improve the last edit, you should "edit" the post. If you only want to rollback to a previous revision, just rollback. Users with < 1000 points (if I'm not mistaken), still get reputation from edits.

Comment: @Maroun Isn't it 2000? Thats when you get edit privilage. Maybe you are thinking about the maximum amount of rep you can get from edits alone which is 1000.

Comment: @AndréKool True.