# I believe my suggested edit was wrongly rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I believe [my suggested edit was wrongly rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22391749). It's one of those edits that look harmful at first, because I removed several paragraphs, but I doubt the reviewers read my reason for editing:

> Comment: Rollback to revision 4: Rev 5 should not have been approved on grounds of "Do not edit your own answer into someone else's answer." The edit in revision 5 is about as unrelated to this particular answer as it could be. Further, they had added incorrect code highlighting, and incorrect edit dates.

There were two different reject reasons given:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Counterpoint: Removing incorrect code highlighting and incorrect edit dates makes it easier to read, so they're not superfluous. Certainly it does not actively harm readability. At first, you might think it "actively harms readability" because I deleted text, except it "harms readability" of content that does not even belong to the post's owner, and really, the answer is better without. In my view, I'm improving the post's readability by removing this third-party edit that should've never happened. I think this person meant to reject with the below reason instead.

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the **post's owner**.

(Emphasis mine.) Counterpoint: The part of the answer I deleted was NOT added by the **post's owner**. It was added in an edit submitted by **another person** (and the edit was NOT approved by the post's owner either, but some additional random other people).

If it indeed should've been rejected, please explain why. If not, what's the path forward?

P.S. Yes, I know you're not supposed to edit in "EDIT:" into your posts, so I considered removing that entirely, but the post's owner edited that in themself, and it helps explain the flow of the post, so simply removing it would actively harm readability, IMO, and I'm not keen to rewrite whole parts of the post just to remove it because I think that could easily start deviating from the post's owner's intent.

Comment: Note: You can tell it's an "edited their answer into another answer" situation in part because the editor repeated (paraphrased, essentially) parts of the answer they edited.

Comment: Another note: I explained as much as I could when I submitted the edit, but I was bumping up against the maximum character limit for edit reasons.

Comment: Yeah, the maximum character limit for edit descriptions seems arbitrary and of little use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not have edit privileges yet (>2000 rep), you can flag the post for a moderator attention as you cannot directly perform a rollback. A moderator can retroactively reject the previous suggested edit, but only if the post was not yet edited afterwards, otherwise the moderator can also rollback directly. See also [What to do with faulty edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366475)

Now, for this particular case, I was going to reject the [previously approved suggested edit (rev.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3267187/revisions), which would automatically create a rollback revision.

However, I noticed in the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3267187/timeline), that the author of the answer had already rejected a *subsequent* [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21531223) by the same editor on the content added in the first approved edit. This means that the author most likely have already seen the changed answer and had no issues with the first edit. Therefore, we could possibly leave the post as it is since it adds value to the answer, and we don't stand to lose from having the additional content added by (rev.5) around.

Comment: Strange. I hadn't seen the post timeline, so good catch. Assuming the original author wanted to keep the edit in Rev 5, the subsequent edit also makes sense to do (otherwise `log_success` is never used, and it calls `log_error` upon success, so it doesn't make as much sense without the additional rejected edit). I wonder if they truly realize their answer has been edited. (For those unfamiliar with Make, adding `@` in front just hides the command from being printed to the console, and doesn't affect any other runtime functionality.)

Answer (score 13):

I think I agree with you on this one.

The tricky thing here is that what you're doing isn't *technically* a rollback; once you have 2K+ rep you can actually issue a rollback to posts.  Since you lack that, you'd be best to flag it for moderator attention and explain what's going on as opposed to going through the review queue, where reviewers may mistake it for a bad edit.